# How to group by date in pandas when the date looks like this: 2017-06-16 09:34:23?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (check image A). And I have been told to group it by type of file (aka. mime_type), size and date (aka. created_at).

How can I split the date by year and month? Any suggestions?

So far I have done the following:

Group by 3 variables: mime_type, created_at and size

```
df_1=df.groupby(['mime_type', 'created_at', 'size']).groups
display(df_1)
```

Group by mime_type. (Check ImageB)

```
df_mime = df.groupby('mime_type')
for name, group in df_mime:
    print(name)
    print(group, '\n', '\n')
```

IMAGE A
[image]

IMAGEB

[image]

Comment: Are you allowed create a new column / update the created_at column to contain just the date part?

Comment: Yes I can make any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'path': [f'p_{i}' for i in range(5)],
    'size': [10] * 5,
    'mime_type': ['mime_type0'] * 5,
    'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] * 2 + ['2020-01-02 23:00:34'] * 2 + ['2020-01-03 23:00:34']
})
print(df)
print()

df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.normalize()

grouped = df.groupby(['mime_type', 'created_at', 'size'])

for group, rows in grouped:
    print(group)
    print(rows)
    print()
```

Output:

```
  path  size   mime_type           created_at
0  p_0    10  mime_type0  2020-01-01 23:00:34
1  p_1    10  mime_type0  2020-01-01 23:00:34
2  p_2    10  mime_type0  2020-01-02 23:00:34
3  p_3    10  mime_type0  2020-01-02 23:00:34
4  p_4    10  mime_type0  2020-01-03 23:00:34

('mime_type0', Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 10)
  path  size   mime_type created_at
0  p_0    10  mime_type0 2020-01-01
1  p_1    10  mime_type0 2020-01-01

('mime_type0', Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'), 10)
  path  size   mime_type created_at
2  p_2    10  mime_type0 2020-01-02
3  p_3    10  mime_type0 2020-01-02

('mime_type0', Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'), 10)
  path  size   mime_type created_at
4  p_4    10  mime_type0 2020-01-03
```

Comment: what does "dt.normalize" do?

Comment: The time component of the datetime is set to 00:00:00

Comment: And if I need to plot the number of plots by month, will that be possible? As you have converted the column "created_at" to datetime?

Comment: To get the month, use `.dt.month`